# How to change select menu background color after selected any option| not option color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have `select option list` in my side panel and i just want to change select background color if the user selected any option. I don't want to change option colors. Simply i want to make as if user select any `option`, apply `mouse hover color` to background.

[image] to [image]

```css
.nav-country-select:hover {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #ced0cf;
}
.nav-country-select:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
.nav-country-select {
  background-color: #e9ece5;
  font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
  color: #333333;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label class="label nav-label">Country</label>
  <select class="btn nav-country-select" id="countrySelect" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="1" selected>Doesn't Matter</option>
    <option value="3">Australia</option>
    <option value="4">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="5">Middle East</option>
    <option value="6">UK</option>
    <option value="7">USA</option>
    <option value="8">Canada</option>
    <option value="9">India</option>
    <option value="10">Other</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Comment: You want to check if the user selected an element of this Dropdown and change the color forever while he's on this site?

Comment: @PatrickMlr yes.. there are many select items in side panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `js` is allowed, try this.

```js
$('#countrySelect').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) $(this).css('background', 'red');
  else $(this).css('background', '#e9ece5');
})
```

```css
.nav-country-select:hover {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #ced0cf;
}
.nav-country-select:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
.nav-country-select {
  background-color: #e9ece5;
  font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
  color: #333333;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
}
.nav-country-select option{
background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label class="label nav-label">Country</label>
  <select class="btn nav-country-select" id="countrySelect" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="" selected>Doesn't Matter</option>
    <option value="3">Australia</option>
    <option value="4">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="5">Middle East</option>
    <option value="6">UK</option>
    <option value="7">USA</option>
    <option value="8">Canada</option>
    <option value="9">India</option>
    <option value="10">Other</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add onchange to the select;

```css
.nav-country-select:hover {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #ced0cf;
}
.nav-country-select:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
.nav-country-select {
  background-color: #e9ece5;
  font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
  color: #333333;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <label class="label nav-label">Country</label>
  <select class="btn nav-country-select" id="countrySelect" onchange="this.style.background = 'gray'" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="1" selected>Doesn't Matter</option>
    <option value="3">Australia</option>
    <option value="4">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="5">Middle East</option>
    <option value="6">UK</option>
    <option value="7">USA</option>
    <option value="8">Canada</option>
    <option value="9">India</option>
    <option value="10">Other</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Jquery**.

```js
    $("#countrySelect").change(function()
    {
     $(".nav-country-select").css("background-color","#2b67c6");

    });
```

```css
    .nav-country-select {
      background-color: #e9ece5;
      font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
      color: #333333;
      height: 35px;
      border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<li>
          <label class="label nav-label">Country</label>
          <select class="btn nav-country-select" id="countrySelect" autocomplete="off">
            <option value="1" selected>Doesn't Matter</option>
            <option value="3">Australia</option>
            <option value="4">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="5">Middle East</option>
            <option value="6">UK</option>
            <option value="7">USA</option>
            <option value="8">Canada</option>
            <option value="9">India</option>
            <option value="10">Other</option>
          </select>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#countrySelect').change(function() {
  if ($(this).val()) $(this).css('background', 'red');
  else $(this).css('background', '#e9ece5');
})
```

```css
.nav-country-select:hover {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #ced0cf;
}
.nav-country-select:focus {
  outline: none !important;
}
.nav-country-select {
  background-color: #e9ece5;
  font-family: Arial, Times, serif;
  color: #333333;
  height: 35px;
  border: 1px solid #bbbcbc;
}
.nav-country-select option{
background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <label class="label nav-label">Country</label>
  <select class="btn nav-country-select" id="countrySelect" autocomplete="off">
    <option value="" selected>Doesn't Matter</option>
    <option value="3">Australia</option>
    <option value="4">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="5">Middle East</option>
    <option value="6">UK</option>
    <option value="7">USA</option>
    <option value="8">Canada</option>
    <option value="9">India</option>
    <option value="10">Other</option>
  </select>
</li>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just add a different background color to option elements so everytime it looks like if some option is selected , select element will have a different color

```
select>option{
 background-color: #ced0cf;
}
```